# Unable to post array via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, post

I am trying to post an array created in js to a php page

```
 var newEventArray = new Array();  
        newEventArray["title"] = title;
        newEventArray["description"] = description;
        newEventArray["type"] = type;
        newEventArray["visibility"] = visibility;
        newEventArray["priority"] = priority;
        newEventArray["start"] = start;
        newEventArray["end"] = end;
        newEventArray["allDay"] = allDay;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/processor.php",
            data: {request: 'createevent',
                requestarray: newEventArray},

            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {

            },
            error: function(data) {
            }
        });
```

but i am unable to get the array at the php end. The array doesnt show when checked with firebug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript Arrays are designed to hold an ordered sequence of items with integer keys. When jQuery converts a data structure into Form URL Encoded data and encounters an array, it will iterate over those integer keys and not over named keys.

Use an Object if you want to have named keys.

Comment: please use an example or correct my code to help me. also, are you saying that the construction of the array iteslf is wrong? cos whe i do a console.log i get the array as expected. challenge now is to get it sent to the php page. Thanks

Comment: Change "Array" to "Object".